# OpenJPA1.2 - lazy load a BLOB

Tags: jpa, db2, jpql, openjpa

I have a very simple JPA entity. It features some simple metadata fields, and ID and a large ~500kB-10MB payload String.

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity{
  @Id
  @GenerateValue(Strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long myEntityId;

  private String metaData1; 
  ..
  private String metaDataN;

  @Lob
  private String payload; // large.
```

}

Most of the time, I am not intersseted in loading in the payload, but simply query the metadata fields. Is there a way to load the payload lazy without creating a specific Entity that wrapps the payload and have a lazy load one-to-one relation with that one from my main entity?

The whole thing is implemented using OpenJPA 1.2 and a DB2 backing database.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
@Lob
@Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private String payload;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also use:

```
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(//some col. name)
private String payload;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate does not load lob as long as it is mapped it as type Lob

Comment: I don't really understand that sentence. In this old question - the mapped type was actually CLOB.